# Diverse doubts about Tor relays

Tags: relays, exit-relays

According to Tor's official website (https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay.html.en), to be a relay I only have to modify the 'torrc' file and add the following information:

ORPort 443
    Exitpolicy reject *: *
    Nickname ididntedittheconfig
    ContactInfo human @ ...

Okay. ***First question:*** But can I configure the "ORPort" field with any other port? Port 443 is used for default HTTPS communications; So ***Second question***: does that mean that a person who is browsing by Tor on an HTTP web page (port 80 or 8080) will not be able to navigate through my relay?

***Third question:*** Adding these parameters to the 'torrc' file, will I be an intermediate node only? Because I suppose to be an exit node the Exitpolicy field has to be configured with ports too, right? Example: ExitPolicy accept: *: 80, accept *: 110 Or has this changed?

***Fourth question:*** This question is *extremely* curious. In an old example of the 'torrc' file (https://svn.torproject.org/svn/tor/tags/tor-0_0_9_5/src/config/torrc.sample.in) this was said:

**################ This section is just for servers #####################
NOTE: If you enable these, you should consider mailing your identity.
key fingerprint to the tor-ops, so we can add you to the list of
servers that clients will trust. See the README for details.**

In the example of the current 'torrc' file (https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/config/torrc.sample.in) this no longer appears. Why?

Also, in the Tor FAQ (https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en) there is a question that is NOT ACCESSIBLE. Specifically this question: "So I can just set a nickname and ORPort and join the network?"

However, on a non-torproject web page (https://archive.li/K3iJY#selection-1815.0-1815.203) this question still appears. And the answer is:

"Yes. But by default users will only use you for the middle hop of their circuits. To become more useful to the network, please send mail to the ops with your key fingerprint and contact information".

**So, the question:** To be an exit node, is it necessary to send an email to The Tor Project? I'm very confused...

***Fifth question:*** I have read that once the file 'torrc' has been modified, the directory authorities must vote and approve the node. Is this still so? And in that case, who votes that a node is valid or not? A human administrator? Automatic software?

Next topic: I have read that to be an entry guard, I have to meet some requirements. Well, here are ***two questions***:

***1.*** Does the first node (or entry guard) to the Tor network know the IP of the Tor client?
***2.*** I have read that to be an entry guard node it is necessary to have a good bandwidth and be a stable node. Who decides that I am prepared to be an input node? A human administrator, or software?

That's all by now. Thank you Tor Stacks volunteers. I'm learning a lot with you.

(Please forget my English; English is not my mother tongue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But can I configure the "ORPort" field with any other port?

Yes. This is arbitrary, 443 can be useful for some users behind weak censorship or firewalls but ultimately the choice of port is entirely at the relay operators discretion.

> does that mean that a person who is browsing by Tor on an HTTP web page (port 80 or 8080) will not be able to navigate through my relay?

No, the ORPort is only used by: Clients using you as an entry point and other relays. It has no impact on how Tor users could use you to route their traffic.

> Adding these parameters to the 'torrc' file, will I be an intermediate node only?

Not only an itermediate node. If your policy specifies `ExitPolicy reject *:*` you will not be an exit. You may however be other nodes in the network, for example a guard, directory, introduction point or rendezvous point. Your suitability to fill these positions is decided by the client and the directory authorities.

> In the example of the current 'torrc' file this no longer appears. Why?

That code an example configuration file are over a decade old. Tor has seen significant improvement since them.

> there is a question that is NOT ACCESSIBLE.

Yup, that looks like a bug on the website. Content renamed, changed or removed but with the old link to it still intact. I've created a ticket for this, [#21519](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21519).

> To be an exit node, is it necessary to send an email to The Tor Project?

No. If you want to avoid confusion then don't read information that's over a decade old, read the current information.

> who votes that a node is valid or not?

The directory authorities are directory servers, each votes and they together create a consensus. The votes are based on various aspects of your relays configuration and it's capacity. More details on this are available in [dir-spec.txt](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt), along with some of the changes made and the rationale for those changes. The consensus is distributed to all Tor clients, a break down of votes made and votes on what are also available at the [consensus-health](https://consensus-health.torproject.org/) website.

> Does the first node...know the IP of the Tor client?

Yes, by virtue of internetworking it must otherwise the client would have no means to connect to the guard and the guard no means to send the responses back to the client.

> Who decides that I am prepared to be an input node?

Software, the directory authorities, by virtue of a human decision on suitable parameters. They are defined in the aforementioned [dir-spec.txt](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt).

Comment: 1/3 Thank you very much as always! However, a doubt: In the past a relay had to provide an e-mail. Okay. And was not this method safer? I explain: It is currently possible for the NSA to prepare many Tor nodes (in the end, nodes are voluntary, and this has advantages and disadvantages).

Comment: 2/3 Imagine then that the NSA launches several nodes to the Tor network. These nodes have a high bandwidth (the NSA has much more budget and capacity than any user). Stable and bandwidth nodes are "privileged" by directory authorities.

Comment: 3/3 Then, it is more possible to reward nodes of the NSA (in this example) than other nodes. However, if it were necessary to provide an email to The Tor Project to be a node, perhaps everything would be safer, right?

Comment: @NewUser The NSA does not need to run nodes, they can already watch and intercept all traffic

Comment: 1/2 I asked a question related to what you say. I know the NSA has the means to monitor submarine cables; In the end I came to the conclusion that although they can monitor the cables, actually if the user use Tor and the HTTPS protocol he/she is more or less safe.

Comment: 2/2 However, if the NSA could control the first and last nodes (having many nodes inside Tor), they could establish a relationship between the first node and the last node, knowing who is using Tor and what websites is visiting.

So that's why I ask: Why is not an email now being requested to be a Tor relay and before it was requested?

(Forget my English; English is not my mother tongue).

Comment: You think email will protect against the NSA while at the same time the NSA are also somehow a Global Passive Adversary with much more budget and capacity? I think you might want to resolve the cognitive dissonance in your own head first, the answer is clearly right infront of you.

Comment: In future A) Use the search feature, all the questions you've asked are answered already and B) Ask one question, concisely, at a time.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I've found the answer also here (https://blog.torproject.org/blog/research-problem-better-guard-rotation-parameters). Arma said: "We once imagined we could run a Tor network only using relays run by people we knew. That approach doesn't scale, especially when anonymity is a function of network diversity. Instead, we need to grow a larger network: the more relays we have, the less impact a new attacking relay can have".

Answer (score 0):

OK, so let's do it step-by-step!

> But can I configure the "ORPort" field with any other port? Port 443 is used for default HTTPS communications;

Yes, you can choose whatever you wish from a free port list. But keep in mind if you will be launching Tor from unprivileged user *from the very beginning*, then you need to use port number greater than 1024(or 2048 on some OSes), also called as an *unprivileged ports*. But you better use 443. Why? Because if people are behind the too-strict firewalls, also called as "facist firewalls" in Tor docs, they do allow only a strict amount of ports on remote side to be accessed. If you will run a bridge, for example obfs3 or 4 - use it for bridge incoming port, otherwise use it as an ORPort, you will maximize your relay usability by improving it's "reachability" for other people.

> So Second question: does that mean that a person who is browsing by Tor on an HTTP web page (port 80 or 8080) will not be able to navigate through my relay?

No, the ports *for Tor itself* are influentive only on the connectivity to the Tor network itself. Once "you're inn" - your requests are tunneled through Tor network by using Tor protocol and because of that fact it's completely unrelated. Your requests are packed into the crypto-onions that contain not just the request data but also a "destination address", i.e. host+port or hostname+port in case of hidden onion service.

> Third question: Adding these parameters to the 'torrc' file, will I be an intermediate node only? Because I suppose to be an exit node the Exitpolicy field has to be configured with ports too, right? Example: ExitPolicy accept: *: 80, accept *: 110 Or has this changed?

Yes and no =) Tor nodes are *basically all the same*, the p2p nodes to be more specific. So *unless* you have specified `ClientOnly 1` in your config - you're a full p2p node, a "middle node". They do have roles, that can also be referred as Flags, and roles are assigned differently. Some of them - like "Exit" and "V2dir" - are assigned **only** if configured by the user in the config of *this very specific node*. Others like Guard, Stable, HSDir, Fast - are assigned by network consensus. I do recommend you to add `DirPort 80` to enable directory("V2Dir") functionality - it won't overload you at all and won't make traffic grow any sensible high, but it will make your node serve a signed cache copies of "Tor directories" that are responsible for network consensus. It will help a lot to all the nodes in your vicinity and in global scale. Some roles are disabling others, for example an "Exit" won't be used as a "Guard". If you're about to be an exit node - you need to explicitly enable via `ExitPolicy accept xxx` and `ExitPolicy accept6 xxx` for IPv4 and IPv6 respecitvely. And here is the trick: `*:<port>` means *Any destination address to port*. Don't try to be a censorship supporter and put there *anything* except an asterisk in host part. It's impossible, for example, to "reject all requests to Google to 443 port* - addresses are changing and you will overload your relay with rubbish. At the end **always** make a `reject *:*` and `reject6 *:*`(if you have IPv6).

> Fourth question: This question is extremely curious. In an old example of the 'torrc' file (https://svn.torproject.org/svn/tor/tags/tor-0_0_9_5/src/config/torrc.sample.in) this was said:
>
> ########## This section is just for servers ##################### NOTE: If you enable these, you should consider mailing your identity. key fingerprint to the tor-ops, so we can add you to the list of servers that clients will trust. See the README for details.

In the example of the current 'torrc' file (https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/config/torrc.sample.in) this no longer appears. Why?

At the earlier days Tor - as all the software - was debugged, and this was needed to keep in touch with the people who were running some kind of functionality that was debugged and/or developed that particular moment. *This is OK*, for any software, not just Tor. Nowdays it's done and working properly so there's no need in it. That's why all the stuff about it was removed - it's obsolete. You don't need to email anyone and/or announce your contacts.

> Fifth question: I have read that once the file 'torrc' has been modified, the directory authorities must vote and approve the node. Is this still so? And in that case, who votes that a node is valid or not? A human administrator? Automatic software?

Yes, network consensus and directories are making automatic voting possible, and that's how it should be. No human factor involved: it's the most mailfunctioning part in most of IT systems, the human factor...

> 1. Does the first node (or entry guard) to the Tor network know the IP of the Tor client?

Yes it does, but it does not know what are you doing in/via Tor network. There's no risk, and in some "last resort" cases you can disable using entry guards by adding `UseEntryGuards 0` in your config. But **this is last resort ONLY method**, you should **not** use it in normal case. To make it clear I'll describe such a last-resort case: you are behind a firewall that somehow syndicates the guard list and blocks access to these addresses on by-ip basis. So if you have "seeded" your instance of Tor in working connection and disabling the guards - you have a chance that the node will be used which is not blocked. Because the **total** node address pool is a *quite a big* to be blocked in a whole, and it's changing frequently - a "jailbreak" scenario here is the really last resort you have. In other cases do not disable it.

> 2. I have read that to be an entry guard node it is necessary to have a good bandwidth and be a stable node. Who decides that I am prepared to be an input node? A human administrator, or software?

Actually - as my experience shows - you need a *stable* bandwidth and long-term-online node. 1Mibps is more than enough to become a guard and I think lesser speeds are too. But it **must** be stable. That makes a great sense: a guard's primary task is to be a gatekeeper, so it should be reachable, online when it's needed and it's connection should actually allow it to fullfill it's task(to let people in).

Comment: "So unless you have specified ClientOnly 1 in your config - you're a full p2p node, a "middle node"" Wrong.

Comment: "If you're about to be an exit node - you need to explicitly enable" Wrong.

Comment: "you can disable using entry guards by adding UseEntryGuards 0 in your config" Users should never do this, I've explained this to you before. This is *never* a good idea. A bridge is *always* a better choice. Stop telling people to do this, it is **never** the right choice. **never**.

Comment: @canonizingironize read the warning near the subject. And yes - we do have different opinions on this matter. So stop yelling your "no/never" stuff every time. Would you be so kind to be more constructive?

Comment: Thank you very much. You said "Some roles are disabling others, for example an "Exit" won't be used as a "Guard" ". Does it mean that an exit node cannot act as an entry Guard at the same time? I ask this because from atlas.torproject.com I have seen some relays have "Exit flag" and "Guard flag" (like this relay: https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/EC116BCB80565A408CE67F8EC3FE3B0B02C3A065) So I do not know if a relay can be an entry guard and an exit relay.

Comment: Physically it can, but it won't be voted for it - and for a sane reason: both roles need bandwidth, so if the node will act like Guard - it will need the speed to let users in, but Exit role will also consume this because it's about to let people go out. Due to single-core crypto code in Tor(for a good reason now, it's not a coding fail) - these two roles will fight each other. So - due to this - an Exit is not taking part in Guard elections. However some alterations are in order to election mechanisms, so you can see such a relays

Comment: Why these roles can be assigned? Maybe they do estimate the system resources and see the cases when roles won't hurt each other much. I didn't looked at the last code changes in that part of Tor - I'm working on another part right now

Comment: Thank you! And... Can a relay acts as an exit relay and as a middle relay AT THE SAME TIME: Routing some networks packets to Internet (or hidden services) and routing at the same time network packets of other Tor clients to other third (exit) nodes?

Comment: Technically - yes, and - observing some of my relays - I can say that this happens, but not very often. The dilemma here is that bandwidth is not a limiting factor, it's pretty cheap and obvious nowdays to have a 20-50Mbps connection even at home. The problem is a single-core crypto. Exits are very important to Tor network because of high demand in "Exiting bandwidth"

Comment: 1/2 Thank you very much! I'm doing a university paper about Tor and that's why I'm asking so many doubts these days. I feel very helped :). So, the last question for now, I promise. This question is about Entry Guard. I've read that Tor "chooses three guards, adding another one if two of those three go down but going back to the original ones if they come back up". But I think this is outdated. I've also read that the Client (Tor) "picks a guard at random and also set an expiry time of 30-60 days. After 30-60 days the clients pick a guard at random again". But I think it is also outdated.

Comment: 2/2 In Tor FAQs it is said this: "Tor client selects a few relays at random to use as entry points, and uses only those relays for her first hop". Ok, but the question is: how many relays does the client select? Because "a few" is a very ambiguous term. And, when does the relay change? 30 days? 60 days? Depends? These are my questions. Thank you again

Comment: 1/2 yes, a Guard role can be longer than 60 days - as my nodes showing me. all the rest seems to be fine. 2/2 usually 2-5, as my measurements showed me some time ago

Comment: by the way - you're not the first one who makes a scientific research about tor and contacting me. You can add me on Facebook and I can answer your questions for your paper if you need. One guy even asked me about an interview for his paper, it's no problem to make - I'm a scientific researcher too and glad to help and share the experience

Comment: This is absolute rubbish, a relay can be a Guard and an Exit and the same time.

Comment: Do not add Alexey on Facebook, he has within the space of this answer given you bad information at least 4 times, *at least* and he is *not* a scientific researcher.

Comment: @canonizingironize well, what grounds do you have to call me *not* a scientific researcher? I'm curious :)

Comment: Being consistently wrong and repeating said falsehoods after being corrected multiple times. I tried constructive criticism, you ignored it so now I'm just warning users about you instead :)